# SQLite database to MySQL database daily migration / updating new fields

Tags: java, php, mysql, sqlite, migration

I have a SQLite database that is created by reading some data in PDF files using Java. Every day (or almost) I have new PDF files to read that create new rows in some tables in my SQLite database.

Eventually, what I'd like to do is make the data in that database available on the internet using a MySQL database accessed by my website. The thing is, I have searched on Google, to no avail, how to migrate my database to MySQL. Of course I have found some programs to do so, but they don't let me do it in an automated manner every day at midnight.

Also, if it's possible, I'd rather do it another way: only updating the new rows that were added and migrate only those instead of recreating the whole database daily.

I don't know what the best way to do something like this is, so if the tags are wrong, I'm sorry about it.

The computer that runs the java program to create / update the SQLite database is running Windows Vista, if it matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could include a timestamp in your SQLite table and set the default value to the time when the record was inserted (`default now` should do the trick). Then, you'd need a table in your MySQL database (or your SQLite database, whichever works better for you) that contains a single timestamp, this will be your "last imported time".

When it is time to do your data transfer:

- Grab the last-imported-time.
- Store the current timestamp in **t**.
- Grab everything from your SQLite database that is newer than **t** and copy it to your MySQL database.
- Update the last-imported-time in your database to **t** from above.

Storing the timestamp that you're using in **t** helps you avoid missing anything.

If you're also updating things in your SQLite database rather than just inserting things, then you could add another timestamp for the "last modified time". Then apply the same logic as above with "copy" replaced with "update" or "delete and re-insert".

Comment: This is a great idea. That's what I'm going to do, thanks! The only thing, though, is that I don't actually know how to copy the data from my SQLite database to my MySQL database in an automated manner. I can do it using some converters, but it requires me to do it manually, which is not what I want to do... Do you have any idea on how I should approach this problem?

Comment: @Adam: If you're only dealing with a small amount of data (say a couple thousand records or so) then you could do it by opening a connection to your SQLite database and another connection to MySQL, then read from SQLite and write to MySQL. Low level JDBC would probably be sufficient for something like this. I don't know of any tools that would do this for you so you might need to build one yourself. Or give it some time and see if anyone comes along with a fully automated solution. I'm a programmer, I build my own tools :)

Comment: All right, I'm going to try and do that. One of my table has about 145,000 records (and my 5 other tables between 500 and 8000), but it's only a one-time deal. For the daily new records, it's only going to be about 300 records. I'll try to build the tools myself, but I'm only a beginner, so we'll see how it goes. Thanks a lot, your help if very appreciated!

Comment: @Adam: You might be able to do the initial transfer using `sqlite3 -csv` to dump the data and then load that CSV into MySQL using [`mysqlimport`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqlimport.html). Then, a little bit of JDBC for the dailies; remember that you need to keep track of the last-import-time for the dailies and initialize it (possibly by hand) during the initial setup/import step.